# Screen "Hitch" In Picture Slideshow Web Part

Tags: content-editor-web-part, picture-library

I have created a slideshow web part in a Sharepoint 2010 environment. I was first having a problem of the images sizing too small in the web part, but I implemented the solution that "Vadim Gremyachev" advised of on this thread... [Picture Slideshow Web Part image size too small](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66028/picture-slideshow-web-part-image-size-too-small)

But now I'm experiencing a "hitch" of sorts on the screen. Vadim's code works great, but it doesn't look correct when the page first renders.   When the slideshow viewer starts cycling through the pictures in the image library I'm pointing to, the THUMBNAIL view is displayed for a split-second before the full-size image is put up -- so the screen "hitches" a bit. I'm wondering how to fix this.

There are a couple suggestions provided in the thread I'm pointing to above (one by "moonpatrol" posted in November 2016, and one by "Salvatore Di Fazio" posted in April 2013), but I don't know where to insert the code they provided.  I tried inserting what they suggested into Vadim's code, but where I inserted the code didn't work in the end -- and I must admit that I am not a coder, so that explains things.

If anyone can help me with this issue, I would be most appreciative!

but I'd like to know how to make the images -- if/when clicked by a user -- hyperlink-able to another site location.  Is this something that can be done in Sharepoint 2010?  If so, can anyone provide some direction on how to do this?