# Picture Slideshow Web Part image size too small if page contains multiple picture slidershow web parts on same page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, javascript, web-part, picture-library

I want to show full size picture in slideshow web part in SharePoint 2010.
but SharePoint shows images from /_w folder of picture library which are not original and full size images.
I have found very useful link on stack exchange [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66028/picture-slideshow-web-part-image-size-too-small) to show original images instead of showing images from /_w folder.

I have implemented that but the problem is if I have **multiple picture slideshow web parts on same page**, then it only works for first slider for first time. It is not working for remaining sliders.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add add a setTimeout() menthod in the end:

```
setTimeout(SlideshowObjectInitializer, 500);
```